# Cleaning escapes on a user-entered string

Tags: python

I have a user that can enter in text that a program will print after parsing. That is, the user can enter in something like:

```
"Print me\nAnd on a newline now"
```

And it should print as:

```
Print me
And on a newline now
```

The string I have now looks like `OK\n` when I print it and `OK\\n` when I do `repr()` on it. I'm having some difficulty converting this to properly print the newline. The only thing that seems to work now is to manually go through each possible entry and do something like:

```
val = val.replace('\\n', '\n'))
# or, what if they wanted a beep?
# similar to print('\a')
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ast` and `shlex` to get the job done.

```
>>import ast
>>import shlex
>>x = input('Enter the string:')
Enter the string:>? "Print me\nAnd on a newline now"
>>x
'"Print me\\nAnd on a newline now"'
```

**Output**:

```
print(ast.literal_eval(shlex.quote(x)))
"Print me
And on a newline now"
```

**UPDATE**: As pointed by @David542, you can even avoid using `shlex` if you don't want to

```
>>print(ast.literal_eval("'%s'" % x))
"Print me
 And on a newline now"
```

Comment: cool. What about without shlex and just doing: `print(ast.literal_eval("'%s'" % x))` ?

Comment: @David542, That's even cooler.

Comment: Simply interpolating between `''` is not good enough for a variety of reasons. `shlex.quote` can make a real mess of things. Try the input `x = r'''\\ \ \" \\" \\\" \'你好'\n\u062a\xff\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER A}"''' + '\\'` if you really want to test out the quoting mechanism properly. I wrote an answer at the duplicate I just linked, which handles this properly.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, actually I can not agree more; however, the time when I wrote this answer, I was just thinking about the sample provided by OP TBH.